# Using a dataset as "index" to change values in another datasets

Tags: r

I have a first dataset "index"

```
ID     Trial      RT
 1        1       500
 1        2       400
 2        1       200
 2        2       100
[etc...]
```

A second dataset "Experiment", much more longer than "index"

```
 ID     Trial      RT
 1        1       1500
 1        1       2000
 1        2       1400
 1        2       3000
 2        1       1200
 2        1       4000
 2        2       1100
 2        2       5000
[etc...]
```

I want to subtract RT values in "index" from RT "values" in "Experiment", based on a match between ID and Trial across datasets, to obtain a "revised" version of "Experiment":

```
ID     Trial      RT
 1        1       1000
 1        1       1500
 1        2       1000
 1        2       2600
 2        1       1000
 2        1       3800
 2        2       1000
 2        2       4900
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Merge then subtract columns?

Comment: `full_join(index %>% rename(RT1 = RT),Experiment) %>% mutate(RT = RT - RT1) %>% select(-RT1)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Each row of "index" is an "index" for "Experiment". So, when in "index" I have ID = 1 & Trial = 1, RT is 500 (and so so). This value (500) must be subtracted from all the RT rows in "Experiment" that have ID = 1 and Trial = 1. And so on...so I think that I need a sort of "match" function instead of merging.

Comment: Just to say that it works perfectly, thank you!!!